# MacOS Eclipse RCP MenuItem Selection event invalidation

Tags: java, eclipse

MacOS 10.15.5
Eclipse RCP 2020-09

Problem : MenuItem Selection event invalidation

Code :

```
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
    newShell.setImage( Images.getImageDescriptor(ImageConstants.IMG_LoL).createImage() ) ;
    newShell.setText( LoLPlugin.getPluginName() );
    newShell.setBackgroundMode( SWT.INHERIT_DEFAULT ) ;
    newShell.setLayout( new FillLayout() ) ;
    newShell.setMenuBar( createMenuBar(newShell) ) ;
    newShell.setSize( getInitialSize() ) ;
    newShell.setLocation( getInitialLocation( newShell ) ) ;
    newShell.addDisposeListener( e -> { newShell.getImage().dispose() ; saveLocation() ; } ) ;
    newShell.setData( window ) ;
}

private Menu createMenuBar(Shell shell) {       
    Menu mainMenu = new Menu( shell , SWT.BAR ) ;
    
    MenuItem bundleItem = new MenuItem( mainMenu , SWT.PUSH ) ;
    bundleItem.setText( Message.BundleBook_Name ) ;
    bundleItem.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> showBook( BundleBook.ID ) );
    
    MenuItem resourceItem = new MenuItem( mainMenu , SWT.PUSH ) ;
    resourceItem.setText( Message.ResourceBook_Name ) ;
    resourceItem.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> showBook( ResourceBook.ID ) );
    
    MenuItem guideItem = new MenuItem( mainMenu , SWT.PUSH ) ;
    guideItem.setText( Message.GuideBook_Name ) ;
    guideItem.addListener( SWT.Selection , e -> showBook( GuideBook.ID ) ) ;
    
    return mainMenu ;
}

private void showBook( String id ) {
    System.out.println( "MaC OS Cannot execute - Window OS Is OK" ) ;
    bookcase.showBook( id ) ;
}
```

result: MacOS cannot execute , Event not triggered

Window OS Is OK

Comment: Why did you not use `MenuItem#addSelectionListener()`?

Comment: .....This is my preference... Does it matter?

Comment: It's no use using MenuItem#addSelectionListener()...I tried

Comment: @nitind addSelectionListener just ends up using the SWT.Selection style listemer internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have `SWT.PUSH` style menu items directly on the menu bar (at least not on macOS). You need to create `SWT.CASCADE` menu items with the push items as children.

```java
Menu bar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
shell.setMenuBar(bar);

MenuItem fileItem = new MenuItem(bar, SWT.CASCADE);
fileItem.setText("&File");

Menu fileSubMenu = new Menu(shell, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
fileItem.setMenu(fileSubMenu);

MenuItem item = new MenuItem(fileSubMenu, SWT.PUSH);
item.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> System.out.println("Select All"));
item.setText("Select");
```

(Adapted from [this SWT Snippet](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet29.java) and tested on macOS 12.0.1)

Note: If you just want push buttons across the top of the shell use a `ToolBar`.

Comment: think you , I know what to do :)